# For Android, where do I find a complete list of @SuppressLint valid issue ids

Tags: android, lint

At the moment, I need to ignore a string concatenation warning relative to internationalization, but would like to *"learn how to fish"* for other specialized warnings in the future.

Comment: You can also Alt + Enter and, inside the lightbulb option, it will show options to supress the warning for Class/Method/etc. So there's no need to have the whole list at hand, which is really useful.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the tools subfolder from your Android SDK folder, run

```
lint --list
```

Source: http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/suppressing-lint-warnings and scroll down to "Issue Id's"

Comment: Vince had a "spot on" answer, but Miguel provided an authoritative source and an opportunity to learn more about the answer.  Thanks to both.

Comment: Make sure you add %LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\Sdk\tools\bin to your environment PATH variable

Comment: @zarsky You don't need to do it. The answer is just missing "\bin".

Answer (score 36):

Using the version bundled with android studio 1.5.1

lint --list

Valid issue categories:

```
Correctness
Correctness:Messages
Security
Performance
Usability:Typography
Usability:Icons
Usability
Accessibility
Internationalization
Bi-directional Text
```

Valid issue id's:

```
"ContentDescription": Image without contentDescription
"AddJavascriptInterface": addJavascriptInterface Called
"ShortAlarm": Short or Frequent Alarm
"AlwaysShowAction": Usage of showAsAction=always
"ShiftFlags": Dangerous Flag Constant Declaration
"LocalSuppress": @SuppressLint on invalid element
"UniqueConstants": Overlapping Enumeration Constants
"InlinedApi": Using inlined constants on older versions
"Override": Method conflicts with new inherited method
"NewApi": Calling new methods on older versions
"UnusedAttribute": Attribute unused on older versions
"AppCompatMethod": Using Wrong AppCompat Method
"AppCompatResource": Menu namespace
"AppIndexingError": Wrong Usage of App Indexing
"AppIndexingWarning": Missing App Indexing Support
"InconsistentArrays": Inconsistencies in array element counts
"Assert": Assertions
"BackButton": Back button
"ButtonCase": Cancel/OK dialog button capitalization
"ButtonOrder": Button order
"ButtonStyle": Button should be borderless
"ByteOrderMark": Byte order mark inside files
"MissingSuperCall": Missing Super Call
"AdapterViewChildren": AdapterViews cannot have children in XML
"ScrollViewCount": ScrollViews can have only one child
"GetInstance": Cipher.getInstance with ECB
"CommitTransaction": Missing commit() calls
"Recycle": Missing recycle() calls
"ClickableViewAccessibility": Accessibility in Custom Views
"EasterEgg": Code contains easter egg
"StopShip": Code contains STOPSHIP marker
"CustomViewStyleable": Mismatched Styleable/Custom View Name
"CutPasteId": Likely cut & paste mistakes
"SimpleDateFormat": Implied locale in date format
"Deprecated": Using deprecated resources
"MissingPrefix": Missing Android XML namespace
"MangledCRLF": Mangled file line endings
"DuplicateIncludedIds": Duplicate ids across layouts combined with include
      tags
"DuplicateIds": Duplicate ids within a single layout
"DuplicateDefinition": Duplicate definitions of resources
"ReferenceType": Incorrect reference types
"ExtraText": Extraneous text in resource files
"FieldGetter": Using getter instead of field
"FullBackupContent": Valid Full Backup Content File
"ValidFragment": Fragment not instantiatable
"PackageManagerGetSignatures": Potential Multiple Certificate Exploit
"GradleCompatible": Incompatible Gradle Versions
"AndroidGradlePluginVersion": Incompatible Android Gradle Plugin
"GradleDependency": Obsolete Gradle Dependency
"GradleDeprecated": Deprecated Gradle Construct
"GradleGetter": Gradle Implicit Getter Call
"GradleIdeError": Gradle IDE Support Issues
"GradlePath": Gradle Path Issues
"GradleDynamicVersion": Gradle Dynamic Version
"StringShouldBeInt": String should be int
"NewerVersionAvailable": Newer Library Versions Available
"AccidentalOctal": Accidental Octal
"GridLayout": GridLayout validation
"HandlerLeak": Handler reference leaks
"HardcodedDebugMode": Hardcoded value of android:debuggable in the manifest
"HardcodedText": Hardcoded text
"IconDuplicatesConfig": Identical bitmaps across various configurations
"IconDuplicates": Duplicated icons under different names
"GifUsage": Using .gif format for bitmaps is discouraged
"IconColors": Icon colors do not follow the recommended visual style
"IconDensities": Icon densities validation
"IconDipSize": Icon density-independent size validation
"IconExpectedSize": Icon has incorrect size
"IconExtension": Icon format does not match the file extension
"IconLauncherShape": The launcher icon shape should use a distinct silhouette
"IconLocation": Image defined in density-independent drawable folder
"IconMissingDensityFolder": Missing density folder
"IconMixedNinePatch": Clashing PNG and 9-PNG files
"IconNoDpi": Icon appears in both -nodpi and dpi folders
"IconXmlAndPng": Icon is specified both as .xml file and as a bitmap
"IncludeLayoutParam": Ignored layout params on include
"DisableBaselineAlignment": Missing baselineAligned attribute
"InefficientWeight": Inefficient layout weight
"NestedWeights": Nested layout weights
"Orientation": Missing explicit orientation
"Suspicious0dp": Suspicious 0dp dimension
"InvalidPackage": Package not included in Android
"DrawAllocation": Memory allocations within drawing code
"UseSparseArrays": HashMap can be replaced with SparseArray
"UseValueOf": Should use valueOf instead of new
"JavascriptInterface": Missing @JavascriptInterface on methods
"LabelFor": Missing labelFor attribute
"InconsistentLayout": Inconsistent Layouts
"InflateParams": Layout Inflation without a Parent
"DefaultLocale": Implied default locale in case conversion
"LocaleFolder": Wrong locale name
"InvalidResourceFolder": Invalid Resource Folder
"WrongRegion": Suspicious Language/Region Combination
"UseAlpha2": Using 3-letter Codes
"LogConditional": Unconditional Logging Calls
"LongLogTag": Too Long Log Tags
"LogTagMismatch": Mismatched Log Tags
"AllowBackup": Missing allowBackup attribute
"MissingApplicationIcon": Missing application icon
"DeviceAdmin": Malformed Device Admin
"DuplicateActivity": Activity registered more than once
"DuplicateUsesFeature": Feature declared more than once
"GradleOverrides": Value overridden by Gradle build script
"IllegalResourceRef": Name and version must be integer or string, not
      resource
"MipmapIcons": Use Mipmap Launcher Icons
"MockLocation": Using mock location provider in production
"MultipleUsesSdk": Multiple <uses-sdk> elements in the manifest
"ManifestOrder": Incorrect order of elements in manifest
"MissingVersion": Missing application name/version
"OldTargetApi": Target SDK attribute is not targeting latest version
"UniquePermission": Permission names are not unique
"UsesMinSdkAttributes": Minimum SDK and target SDK attributes not defined
"WrongManifestParent": Wrong manifest parent
"ManifestTypo": Typos in manifest tags
"FloatMath": Using FloatMath instead of Math
"MergeRootFrame": FrameLayout can be replaced with <merge> tag
"InnerclassSeparator": Inner classes should use $ rather than .
"Instantiatable": Registered class is not instantiatable
"MissingRegistered": Missing registered class
"MissingId": Fragments should specify an id or tag
"LibraryCustomView": Custom views in libraries should use res-auto-namespace
"ResAuto": Hardcoded Package in Namespace
"NamespaceTypo": Misspelled namespace declaration
"UnusedNamespace": Unused namespace
"NegativeMargin": Negative Margins
"NestedScrolling": Nested scrolling widgets
"NfcTechWhitespace": Whitespace in NFC tech lists
"UnlocalizedSms": SMS phone number missing country code
"ObsoleteLayoutParam": Obsolete layout params
"OnClick": onClick method does not exist
"Overdraw": Overdraw: Painting regions more than once
"DalvikOverride": Method considered overridden by Dalvik
"OverrideAbstract": Not overriding abstract methods on older platforms
"ParcelCreator": Missing Parcelable CREATOR field
"UnusedQuantity": Unused quantity translations
"MissingQuantity": Missing quantity translation
"ImpliedQuantity": Implied Quantities
"ExportedPreferenceActivity": PreferenceActivity should not be exported
"PackagedPrivateKey": Packaged private key
"PrivateResource": Using private resources
"ProguardSplit": Proguard.cfg file contains generic Android rules
"Proguard": Using obsolete ProGuard configuration
"PropertyEscape": Incorrect property escapes
"UsingHttp": Using HTTP instead of HTTPS
"SpUsage": Using dp instead of sp for text sizes
"InOrMmUsage": Using mm or in dimensions
"PxUsage": Using 'px' dimension
"SmallSp": Text size is too small
"Registered": Class is not registered in the manifest
"RelativeOverlap": Overlapping items in RelativeLayout
"RequiredSize": Missing layout_width or layout_height attributes
"AaptCrash": Potential AAPT crash
"ResourceCycle": Cycle in resource definitions
"ResourceName": Resource with Wrong Prefix
"RtlCompat": Right-to-left text compatibility issues
"RtlEnabled": Using RTL attributes without enabling RTL support
"RtlSymmetry": Padding and margin symmetry
"RtlHardcoded": Using left/right instead of start/end attributes
"ScrollViewSize": ScrollView size validation
"SdCardPath": Hardcoded reference to /sdcard
"SecureRandom": Using a fixed seed with SecureRandom
"TrulyRandom": Weak RNG
"ExportedContentProvider": Content provider does not require permission
"ExportedReceiver": Receiver does not require permission
"ExportedService": Exported service does not require permission
"GrantAllUris": Content provider shares everything
"WorldReadableFiles": openFileOutput() call passing MODE_WORLD_READABLE
"WorldWriteableFiles": openFileOutput() call passing MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE
"ServiceCast": Wrong system service casts
"SetJavaScriptEnabled": Using setJavaScriptEnabled
"CommitPrefEdits": Missing commit() on SharedPreference editor
"SignatureOrSystemPermissions": signatureOrSystem permissions declared
"SQLiteString": Using STRING instead of TEXT
"StateListReachable": Unreachable state in a <selector>
"StringFormatCount": Formatting argument types incomplete or inconsistent
"StringFormatMatches": String.format string doesn't match the XML format
      string
"StringFormatInvalid": Invalid format string
"PluralsCandidate": Potential Plurals
"UseCheckPermission": Using the result of check permission calls
"CheckResult": Ignoring results
"ResourceAsColor": Should pass resolved color instead of resource id
"MissingPermission": Missing Permissions
"Range": Outside Range
"ResourceType": Wrong Resource Type
"WrongThread": Wrong Thread
"WrongConstant": Incorrect constant
"ProtectedPermissions": Using system app permission
"TextFields": Missing inputType or hint
"TextViewEdits": TextView should probably be an EditText instead
"SelectableText": Dynamic text should probably be selectable
"MenuTitle": Missing menu title
"ShowToast": Toast created but not shown
"TooDeepLayout": Layout hierarchy is too deep
"TooManyViews": Layout has too many views
"ExtraTranslation": Extra translation
"MissingTranslation": Incomplete translation
"Typos": Spelling error
"TypographyDashes": Hyphen can be replaced with dash
"TypographyEllipsis": Ellipsis string can be replaced with ellipsis character
"TypographyFractions": Fraction string can be replaced with fraction
      character
"TypographyOther": Other typographical problems
"TypographyQuotes": Straight quotes can be replaced with curvy quotes
"UnusedResources": Unused resources
"UnusedIds": Unused id
"UseCompoundDrawables": Node can be replaced by a TextView with compound
      drawables
"UselessLeaf": Useless leaf layout
"UselessParent": Useless parent layout
"EnforceUTF8": Encoding used in resource files is not UTF-8
"ViewConstructor": Missing View constructors for XML inflation
"ViewHolder": View Holder Candidates
"ViewTag": Tagged object leaks
"WrongViewCast": Mismatched view type
"Wakelock": Incorrect WakeLock usage
"WebViewLayout": WebViews in wrap_content parents
"WrongCall": Using wrong draw/layout method
"WrongCase": Wrong case for view tag
"InvalidId": Invalid ID declaration
"NotSibling": RelativeLayout Invalid Constraints
"UnknownId": Reference to an unknown id
"UnknownIdInLayout": Reference to an id that is not in the current layout
"SuspiciousImport": 'import android.R' statement
```

Answer (score 5):

From command line run the following:

```
lint --list
```

This assumes you have the Android SDK in your $PATH. If not, you'll have to navigate to the tools folder of the Android SDK, where you'll find the lint executable.

Comment: Looks like it actually needs to be %LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\sdk\tools\bin, not just ...\sdk folder

Answer (score 1):

From a windows command prompt:

```bat
cd %LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\sdk\tools
lint --list
```

Comment: I actually needed to go to %LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\sdk\tools\bin to be able to use it, not just ...\tools. You can also just add it to environment PATH variable.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to `local.properties` in your Android project
2. Find `sdk.dir`
3. Go there (via console)
4. Go to `tools/bin` (so full path is: `<path from sdk.dir>/tools/bin`)
5. Run `./lint --list` (on mac/Linux) or `lint --list` on Windows

```
$ ./lint --version
lint: version 26.1.1
```

and

```
$ ./lint --list
Valid issue categories:
    Correctness
    Correctness:Messages
    Correctness:Chrome OS
    Security
    Performance
    Usability:Typography
    Usability:Icons
    Usability
    Accessibility
    Internationalization
    Internationalization:Bidirectional Text

Valid issue id's:
"ContentDescription": Image without contentDescription
"AddJavascriptInterface": addJavascriptInterface Called
"ShortAlarm": Short or Frequent Alarm
"AllCaps": Combining textAllCaps and markup
"AllowAllHostnameVerifier": Insecure HostnameVerifier
"AlwaysShowAction": Usage of showAsAction=always
"InvalidUsesTagAttribute": Invalid name attribute for uses element.
"MissingIntentFilterForMediaSearch": Missing intent-filter with action android.media.action.MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH
"MissingMediaBrowserServiceIntentFilter": Missing intent-filter with action android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService.
"MissingOnPlayFromSearch": Missing onPlayFromSearch.
"ImpliedTouchscreenHardware": Hardware feature touchscreen not explicitly marked as optional
"MissingTvBanner": TV Missing Banner
"MissingLeanbackLauncher": Missing Leanback Launcher Intent Filter.
"MissingLeanbackSupport": Missing Leanback Support.
"PermissionImpliesUnsupportedHardware": Permission Implies Unsupported Hardware
"UnsupportedTvHardware": Unsupported TV Hardware Feature
"SupportAnnotationUsage": Incorrect support annotation usage
"ShiftFlags": Dangerous Flag Constant Declaration
"LocalSuppress": @SuppressLint on invalid element
"SwitchIntDef": Missing @IntDef in Switch
"UniqueConstants": Overlapping Enumeration Constants
"InlinedApi": Using inlined constants on older versions
"Override": Method conflicts with new inherited method
"ObsoleteSdkInt": Obsolete SDK_INT Version Check
"NewApi": Calling new methods on older versions
"UnusedAttribute": Attribute unused on older versions
"AppCompatMethod": Using Wrong AppCompat Method
"AppCompatCustomView": Appcompat Custom Widgets
"AppCompatResource": Menu namespace
"GoogleAppIndexingApiWarning": Missing support for Firebase App Indexing Api
"GoogleAppIndexingWarning": Missing support for Firebase App Indexing
"AppLinksAutoVerifyError": App Links Auto Verification Failure
"AppLinksAutoVerifyWarning": Potential App Links Auto Verification Failure
"AppLinkUrlError": URL not supported by app for Firebase App Indexing
"TestAppLink": Unmatched URLs
"InconsistentArrays": Inconsistencies in array element counts
"Assert": Assertions
"BadHostnameVerifier": Insecure HostnameVerifier
"BatteryLife": Battery Life Issues
"BackButton": Back button
"ButtonCase": Cancel/OK dialog button capitalization
"ButtonOrder": Button order
"ButtonStyle": Button should be borderless
"ByteOrderMark": Byte order mark inside files
"MissingSuperCall": Missing Super Call
"AdapterViewChildren": AdapterViews cannot have children in XML
"ScrollViewCount": ScrollViews can have only one child
"PermissionImpliesUnsupportedChromeOsHardware": Permission Implies Unsupported Chrome OS Hardware
"UnsupportedChromeOsHardware": Unsupported Chrome OS Hardware Feature
"GetInstance": Cipher.getInstance with ECB
"CommitTransaction": Missing commit() calls
"Recycle": Missing recycle() calls
"CommitPrefEdits": Missing commit() on SharedPreference editor
"ApplySharedPref": Use apply() on SharedPreferences
"ClickableViewAccessibility": Accessibility in Custom Views
"EasterEgg": Code contains easter egg
"StopShip": Code contains STOPSHIP marker
"MissingConstraints": Missing Constraints in ConstraintLayout
"VulnerableCordovaVersion": Vulnerable Cordova Version
"CustomViewStyleable": Mismatched Styleable/Custom View Name
"CutPasteId": Likely cut & paste mistakes
"SimpleDateFormat": Implied locale in date format
"SetTextI18n": TextView Internationalization
"Deprecated": Using deprecated resources
"MissingPrefix": Missing Android XML namespace
"MangledCRLF": Mangled file line endings
"DuplicateIncludedIds": Duplicate ids across layouts combined with include tags
"DuplicateIds": Duplicate ids within a single layout
"DuplicateDefinition": Duplicate definitions of resources
"ReferenceType": Incorrect reference types
"StringEscaping": Invalid string escapes
"UnpackedNativeCode": Missing android:extractNativeLibs=false
"UnsafeDynamicallyLoadedCode": load used to dynamically load code
"UnsafeNativeCodeLocation": Native code outside library directory
"EllipsizeMaxLines": Combining Ellipsize and Maxlines
"ExifInterface": Using android.media.ExifInterface
"ExtraText": Extraneous text in resource files
"FieldGetter": Using getter instead of field
"InvalidAnalyticsName": Invalid Analytics Name
"MissingFirebaseInstanceTokenRefresh": Missing Firebase Instance ID Token Refresh
"FontValidationError": Validation of font files
"FontValidationWarning": Validation of font files
"FullBackupContent": Valid Full Backup Content File
"ValidFragment": Fragment not instantiatable
"GetContentDescriptionOverride": Overriding getContentDescription() on a View
"PackageManagerGetSignatures": Potential Multiple Certificate Exploit
"AccidentalOctal": Accidental Octal
"UseOfBundledGooglePlayServices": Use of bundled version of Google Play services
"GradleCompatible": Incompatible Gradle Versions
"GradleDependency": Obsolete Gradle Dependency
"GradleDeprecated": Deprecated Gradle Construct
"DevModeObsolete": Dev Mode Obsolete
"DuplicatePlatformClasses": Duplicate Platform Classes
"GradleGetter": Gradle Implicit Getter Call
"GradlePluginVersion": Incompatible Android Gradle Plugin
"HighAppVersionCode": VersionCode too high
"GradleIdeError": Gradle IDE Support Issues
"GradlePath": Gradle Path Issues
"GradleDynamicVersion": Gradle Dynamic Version
"NotInterpolated": Incorrect Interpolation
"StringShouldBeInt": String should be int
"NewerVersionAvailable": Newer Library Versions Available
"MinSdkTooLow": API Version Too Low
"GridLayout": GridLayout validation
"HandlerLeak": Handler reference leaks
"HardcodedDebugMode": Hardcoded value of android:debuggable in the manifest
"HardcodedText": Hardcoded text
"HardwareIds": Hardware Id Usage
"IconDuplicatesConfig": Identical bitmaps across various configurations
"IconDuplicates": Duplicated icons under different names
"GifUsage": Using .gif format for bitmaps is discouraged
"IconColors": Icon colors do not follow the recommended visual style
"IconDensities": Icon densities validation
"IconDipSize": Icon density-independent size validation
"IconExpectedSize": Icon has incorrect size
"IconExtension": Icon format does not match the file extension
"IconLauncherShape": The launcher icon shape should use a distinct silhouette
"IconLocation": Image defined in density-independent drawable folder
"IconMissingDensityFolder": Missing density folder
"IconMixedNinePatch": Clashing PNG and 9-PNG files
"IconNoDpi": Icon appears in both -nodpi and dpi folders
"IconXmlAndPng": Icon is specified both as .xml file and as a bitmap
"ConvertToWebp": Convert to WebP
"WebpUnsupported": WebP Unsupported
"IncludeLayoutParam": Ignored layout params on include
"DisableBaselineAlignment": Missing baselineAligned attribute
"InefficientWeight": Inefficient layout weight
"NestedWeights": Nested layout weights
"Orientation": Missing explicit orientation
"Suspicious0dp": Suspicious 0dp dimension
"InstantApps": Instant App Issues
"DuplicateDivider": Unnecessary Divider Copy
"TrustAllX509TrustManager": Insecure TLS/SSL trust manager
"InvalidImeActionId": Invalid imeActionId declaration
"InvalidPackage": Package not included in Android
"DrawAllocation": Memory allocations within drawing code
"UseSparseArrays": HashMap can be replaced with SparseArray
"UseValueOf": Should use valueOf instead of new
"JavascriptInterface": Missing @JavascriptInterface on methods
"JobSchedulerService": JobScheduler problems
"KeyboardInaccessibleWidget": Keyboard inaccessible widget
"LabelFor": Missing labelFor attribute
"InconsistentLayout": Inconsistent Layouts
"InflateParams": Layout Inflation without a Parent
"StaticFieldLeak": Static Field Leaks
"DefaultLocale": Implied default locale in case conversion
"LocaleFolder": Wrong locale name
"GetLocales": Locale crash
"InvalidResourceFolder": Invalid Resource Folder
"WrongRegion": Suspicious Language/Region Combination
"UseAlpha2": Using 3-letter Codes
"LogConditional": Unconditional Logging Calls
"LongLogTag": Too Long Log Tags
"LogTagMismatch": Mismatched Log Tags
"AllowBackup": AllowBackup/FullBackupContent Problems
"MissingApplicationIcon": Missing application icon
"DeviceAdmin": Malformed Device Admin
"DuplicateActivity": Activity registered more than once
"DuplicateUsesFeature": Feature declared more than once
"GradleOverrides": Value overridden by Gradle build script
"IllegalResourceRef": Name and version must be integer or string, not resource
"MipmapIcons": Use Mipmap Launcher Icons
"MockLocation": Using mock location provider in production
"MultipleUsesSdk": Multiple <uses-sdk> elements in the manifest
"ManifestOrder": Incorrect order of elements in manifest
"MissingVersion": Missing application name/version
"OldTargetApi": Target SDK attribute is not targeting latest version
"UniquePermission": Permission names are not unique
"UsesMinSdkAttributes": Minimum SDK and target SDK attributes not defined
"WearableBindListener": Usage of Android Wear BIND_LISTENER is deprecated
"WrongManifestParent": Wrong manifest parent
"InvalidPermission": Invalid Permission Attribute
"ManifestResource": Manifest Resource References
"ManifestTypo": Typos in manifest tags
"FloatMath": Using FloatMath instead of Math
"MergeMarker": Code contains merge marker
"MergeRootFrame": FrameLayout can be replaced with <merge> tag
"IncompatibleMediaBrowserServiceCompatVersion": Obsolete version of MediaBrowserServiceCompat
"InnerclassSeparator": Inner classes should use $ rather than .
"Instantiatable": Registered class is not instantiatable
"MissingRegistered": Missing registered class
"MissingId": Fragments should specify an id or tag
"LibraryCustomView": Custom views in libraries should use res-auto-namespace
"ResAuto": Hardcoded Package in Namespace
"NamespaceTypo": Misspelled namespace declaration
"UnusedNamespace": Unused namespace
"NegativeMargin": Negative Margins
"NestedScrolling": Nested scrolling widgets
"NetworkSecurityConfig": Valid Network Security Config File
"MissingBackupPin": Missing Backup Pin
"PinSetExpiry": Validate <pin-set> expiration attribute
"NfcTechWhitespace": Whitespace in NFC tech lists
"UnlocalizedSms": SMS phone number missing country code
"ObjectAnimatorBinding": Incorrect ObjectAnimator Property
"AnimatorKeep": Missing @Keep for Animated Properties
"ObsoleteLayoutParam": Obsolete layout params
"OnClick": onClick method does not exist
"Overdraw": Overdraw: Painting regions more than once
"DalvikOverride": Method considered overridden by Dalvik
"OverrideAbstract": Not overriding abstract methods on older platforms
"ParcelCreator": Missing Parcelable CREATOR field
"UnusedQuantity": Unused quantity translations
"MissingQuantity": Missing quantity translation
"ImpliedQuantity": Implied Quantities
"ExportedPreferenceActivity": PreferenceActivity should not be exported
"PrivateApi": Using Private APIs
"PackagedPrivateKey": Packaged private key
"PrivateResource": Using private resources
"ProguardSplit": Proguard.cfg file contains generic Android rules
"Proguard": Using obsolete ProGuard configuration
"PropertyEscape": Incorrect property escapes
"UsingHttp": Using HTTP instead of HTTPS
"SpUsage": Using dp instead of sp for text sizes
"InOrMmUsage": Using mm or in dimensions
"PxUsage": Using 'px' dimension
"SmallSp": Text size is too small
"ParcelClassLoader": Default Parcel Class Loader
"PendingBindings": Missing Pending Bindings
"RecyclerView": RecyclerView Problems
"Registered": Class is not registered in the manifest
"RelativeOverlap": Overlapping items in RelativeLayout
"RequiredSize": Missing layout_width or layout_height attributes
"AaptCrash": Potential AAPT crash
"ResourceCycle": Cycle in resource definitions
"ResourceName": Resource with Wrong Prefix
"ValidRestrictions": Invalid Restrictions Descriptor
"RtlCompat": Right-to-left text compatibility issues
"RtlEnabled": Using RTL attributes without enabling RTL support
"RtlSymmetry": Padding and margin symmetry
"RtlHardcoded": Using left/right instead of start/end attributes
"ScrollViewSize": ScrollView size validation
"SdCardPath": Hardcoded reference to /sdcard
"SecureRandom": Using a fixed seed with SecureRandom
"TrulyRandom": Weak RNG
"ExportedContentProvider": Content provider does not require permission
"ExportedReceiver": Receiver does not require permission
"ExportedService": Exported service does not require permission
"SetWorldReadable": File.setReadable() used to make file world-readable
"SetWorldWritable": File.setWritable() used to make file world-writable
"GrantAllUris": Content provider shares everything
"WorldReadableFiles": openFileOutput() or similar call passing MODE_WORLD_READABLE
"WorldWriteableFiles": openFileOutput() or similar call passing MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE
"ServiceCast": Wrong system service casts
"WifiManagerLeak": WifiManager Leak
"WifiManagerPotentialLeak": WifiManager Potential Leak
"SetJavaScriptEnabled": Using setJavaScriptEnabled
"SignatureOrSystemPermissions": signatureOrSystem permissions declared
"SQLiteString": Using STRING instead of TEXT
"SSLCertificateSocketFactoryCreateSocket": Insecure call to SSLCertificateSocketFactory.createSocket()
"SSLCertificateSocketFactoryGetInsecure": Call to SSLCertificateSocketFactory.getInsecure()
"StateListReachable": Unreachable state in a <selector>
"AuthLeak": Code might contain an auth leak
"StringFormatCount": Formatting argument types incomplete or inconsistent
"StringFormatMatches": String.format string doesn't match the XML format string
"StringFormatInvalid": Invalid format string
"PluralsCandidate": Potential Plurals
"UseCheckPermission": Using the result of check permission calls
"CheckResult": Ignoring results
"ResourceAsColor": Should pass resolved color instead of resource id
"MissingPermission": Missing Permissions
"Range": Outside Range
"ResourceType": Wrong Resource Type
"RestrictedApi": Restricted API
"WrongThread": Wrong Thread
"WrongConstant": Incorrect constant
"VisibleForTests": Visible Only For Tests
"ProtectedPermissions": Using system app permission
"TextFields": Missing inputType or hint
"TextViewEdits": TextView should probably be an EditText instead
"SelectableText": Dynamic text should probably be selectable
"MenuTitle": Missing menu title
"ShowToast": Toast created but not shown
"TooDeepLayout": Layout hierarchy is too deep
"TooManyViews": Layout has too many views
"ExtraTranslation": Extra translation
"MissingTranslation": Incomplete translation
"Typos": Spelling error
"TypographyDashes": Hyphen can be replaced with dash
"TypographyEllipsis": Ellipsis string can be replaced with ellipsis character
"TypographyFractions": Fraction string can be replaced with fraction character
"TypographyOther": Other typographical problems
"TypographyQuotes": Straight quotes can be replaced with curvy quotes
"UnsafeProtectedBroadcastReceiver": Unsafe Protected BroadcastReceiver
"UnprotectedSMSBroadcastReceiver": Unprotected SMS BroadcastReceiver
"UnusedResources": Unused resources
"UnusedIds": Unused id
"UseCompoundDrawables": Node can be replaced by a TextView with compound drawables
"UselessLeaf": Useless leaf layout
"UselessParent": Useless parent layout
"EnforceUTF8": Encoding used in resource files is not UTF-8
"VectorRaster": Vector Image Generation
"VectorDrawableCompat": Using VectorDrawableCompat
"VectorPath": Long vector paths
"InvalidVectorPath": Invalid vector paths
"ViewConstructor": Missing View constructors for XML inflation
"ViewHolder": View Holder Candidates
"ViewTag": Tagged object leaks
"WrongViewCast": Mismatched view type
"FindViewByIdCast": Add Explicit Cast
"Wakelock": Incorrect WakeLock usage
"WakelockTimeout": Using wakeLock without timeout
"InvalidWearFeatureAttribute": Invalid attribute for Wear uses-feature
"WearStandaloneAppFlag": Invalid or missing Wear standalone app flag
"WebViewLayout": WebViews in wrap_content parents
"WrongCall": Using wrong draw/layout method
"WrongCase": Wrong case for view tag
"InvalidId": Invalid ID declaration
"NotSibling": RelativeLayout Invalid Constraints
"UnknownId": Reference to an unknown id
"UnknownIdInLayout": Reference to an id that is not in the current layout
"SuspiciousImport": 'import android.R' statement
"WrongFolder": Resource file in the wrong res folder
"WrongThreadInterprocedural": Wrong Thread (Interprocedural)
```

You can always use just `@Suppress`, for example when you don't like Kotlin Elvis Operator (`?:`), so instead of:

```
val user: User = getUser() ?: return null
```

you can write:

```
val user: User? = getUser()

@Suppress
if (user == null) {
    return null
}
```