# How can I run AndroidStudio code inspection in the terminal

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, lint

I'm developing Android app with kotlin. I wonder how can I run the AndroidStudio code inspection in the terminal. I know android lint. But many of the inspection are not check by running `./gradlew lint`. For example, if I wrote

```
var name = "chris"
Log.d("mytag", name)
```

AndroidStudio code inspection would remind my that `name` is never changed and could be change to `val name = "chris"`. But when I run `./gradlew lint`, this improvement option is not in the result report.

How can I run the inspection in the terminal? That way, I can make a gradle task to check the code and gradually introduce some good practice to my team.

Comment: Maybe these links help: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips.html#configure-lint-options
For finding possible lint options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28591726/for-android-where-do-i-find-a-complete-list-of-suppresslint-valid-issue-ids

Answer (score 0):

Just as what said in [official doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint#manuallyRunInspections),

> You can manually run configured lint **and** other IDE inspections by selecting **Analyze > Inspect Code**.

the warning "*var* could be changed to *val*" comes from so-called `other IDE inspections`.
There is not many documents about running `IDE inspections` from command line, but I found [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/command-line-code-inspector.html) which helped me a lot.
If you are using Android Studio instead of IntelliJ IDEA, the shell script is named not `idea.sh` but `studio.sh`, which can be found in the `bin` folder locates in where you install your Android Studio.
Actually, in the `bin` folder there is a shell script named `inspect.sh` you can use directly instead of `studio.sh inspect`.