# lint.xml file is not working for UnusedImport and RedundantSemicolon names in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, lint

I created a `lint.xml` file at the root of my project but Android Studio didn't apply the rules defined there to my source code.

Actually, I need two rules that either exist in Inspections of Android Studio(`File -> Settings... -> Editor -> Inspections`):

1. Unused import directive
2. Redundant semicolon

under `Kotlin -> Redundant constructs`

I generate the warnings and `@Suppress` them with `UnusedImport` and `RedundantSemicolon` names respectively and it worked properly.

The problem arose when I decide to configure the above action in the `lint.xml` file. for that, I create this file as follows at the root of my project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<lint>
    <issue id="UnusedImport" severity="error" />
    <issue id="RedundantSemicolon" severity="error" />
</lint>
```

And link it with lint extension in my `build.gradle` file in this way

```
lint {
    lintConfig = rootProject.file("lint.xml")
}
```

As you could guess it didn't work and I don't know why?

Thanks for helping anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you are using lint issue id's which don't exist.

The way to find out all the possible lint issue id's is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28591726/for-android-where-do-i-find-a-complete-list-of-suppresslint-valid-issue-ids)